# c++" fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'blabla': No such file or directory" only in Release Build

Tags: c++

whenever I compile my project in the Release build I get this error:

```
Error   29  fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'NX_Win32Wrapper.h': No such file or directory
```

I get another one just like this, just in a different file (the error complains about a different file). The file in the second error is whichever I included first (is on top of the include list), the same goes for the first error, but its right after:

(this is the "main".cpp file,where main() is and GameV2 is my project name

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include "GameV2.h"
```

I know there is now code, but I think I'd have to post everything :P Do you have any suggestion what should I check?

Comment: Check for any #ifdef DEBUG type macros that include iff it's in debug mode.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you're using Visual Studio.

Check the include directories in project properties, for Release target. You set the proper include directories only for Debug target.

Answer (score 3):

You should check the "Additional include directories" - the list should usually be the same for "Debug" and "Release".